# Rule for where to put the larger margin

Tags: page-layout, composition, margin

Below are a couple of pieces that I've designed, and they both have a ledger margin on the top.

But in the case of something like a picture frame with a mat, you would never put the larger margin at the top.

How would I explain to someone learning graphic design why and when you should do this (seeming conflicting spacing)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A mat is not a "page". And do this only with text?

Comment: [Check out “Life on the Margins.” by Joel Friedlander](https://www.createspace.com/en/community/docs/DOC-2191)